# Dual monitors on vmware workstation in OSX

Tags: macos, vmware-workstation

Anyone know or have gotten multiple monitors to work on vmware workstation running the OSX operating system?  I cannot find anyone that has accomplished this and I am wondering if this will be something in future versions of vmware workstation.

Comment: you'll probably have much better luck if you ask this on [su]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, 2017, there is nothing for it and, in my opinion, it won't ever be anything fully supported/provided by VMWare.

Afaik, the macOS Terms and Conditions only allow virtualization of macOS on other macOS hosts. Workstation is a product for Windows, while Fusion is for OSX. As such, if VMWare would allow full support for macOS guests on Windows hosts, they would be an "accomplice" of T&C violation. Again, afaik, VMWare Fusion has full support for virtualizing OSX.